# What's the difference between a Maia and a member of the Istari?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, istari, maiar

I've visited many sites searching this, but haven't found any clear answers. Can somebody please explain what's the difference between a Maia and an Istari? And also, what's the singular form of Istari? Is it Istar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the Maiar more powerful than the Istari?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179275/are-the-maiar-more-powerful-than-the-istari)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you've made a category error.

The Istari *are* Maiar, as discussed in Part Four, chapter I, "The Istari" in *Unfinished Tales*. They are five individual members of that group who were given a specific task and sent to Middle-earth.

And yes, the singular is "Istar".

Comment: Can you provide some textual confirmation of this?

Comment: The answer would be greatly improved if the limitations faced by the Maiar who have accepted to be Istari were explained a little more.

Comment: @Ginasius https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217996